# Why does a smaller capacitance equate to a larger voltage drop physically?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, charge, voltage

I was hoping someone could explain practically/physically why a smaller capacitance has a larger voltage drop than a higher capacitance. The equation is V=Q/C, so based on that it's very easy to see, but I thought the definition of capacitance was the ability to store charge.

Wouldn't a higher capacitance, i.e. storing more charge, create a higher voltage drop? Intuitively this doesn't make much sense to me and I was hoping someone could explain.

Answer (score 2):

A small capacitor charges quickly, infinitesimally small capacitor charges in no time reaches whatever voltage it needs to immediately.

A large capacitor charges slowly, an infinitely large capacitor takes forever to charge and no matter how much you charge it, it will not develop any voltage between terminals.

Answer (score 2):

The word "capacitance" *means* the ratio between the charge and the voltage. If we have two capacitors, and both of them have a charge of \$1 \ \mathrm{\mu C}\$, but one of them has a voltage of \$10 \ \mathrm{V}\$ and the other one has a voltage of \$1 \ \mathrm{V}\$, then the first one is defined as having a capacitance of \$0.1 \ \mathrm{\mu F}\$ and the second one is defined as having a capacitance of  \$1 \ \mathrm{\mu F}\$.

But as you've pointed out, that raises a question: how is it possible for two different capacitors with the same amount of charge to have different voltages? What's the physical mechanism behind that?

The answer comes down to [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Maxwell%27s_equations&oldid=1130925464#Formulation_in_SI_units_convention). If we have [a capacitor made out of two parallel plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Capacitor&oldid=1129230261#Parallel-plate_capacitor), the charge on those two plates generates an electric field, which can be measured in \$\mathrm{V}/\mathrm{m}\$ (volts per meter). Maxwell's equations tell us that if we change the distance between the two plates, the electric field doesn't change—the number of volts per meter stays the same. So if we have more distance, we have more volts, and if we have less distance, we have less volts, even though the amount of charge hasn't changed.

Similarly, if we keep the distance between the plates the same, but we double the *area* of the plates, then we can also double the amount of charge on the plates. If we do this, then the strength of the electric field still doesn't change, so the voltage doesn't change. However, the amount of charge *does* change. That's one way that we can get more charge for the same amount of voltage. By doing the opposite, we can get *less* charge for the same amount of voltage—in other words, more voltage for the same amount of charge.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, a capacitor doesn't "generate" a voltage drop.
A voltage is give from external circuit to the capacitor, as an electromagnetic field.

The term "voltage-drop" is when we're thinking electric current first.
For example, when we are talking about "voltage-drop" of a resistor, one might think the current flowing through the resistor is making the voltage-drop.
But in fact, the current is flowing because some voltage is applied to the resistor.

Likewise, when we say "voltage-drop" of a capacitor in AC circuit, it is for thinking AC current first. When we know the AC current, we can caculate "voltage-drop" of a capacitor by multiplying the impedance. However, the AC current is flowing through the capacitor because the external alternating electromagnetic field is applied.

In this point of view, **the smaller capacitance results the higher impedence at the given frequency.** Thus, voltage-drop is higher.

Comment: So, given an example of two capacitors in series with an AC voltage, why does the capacitor with a smaller capacitance result in a larger voltage drop when calculating. I guess I'm still not understanding because shouldn't there be some physical reason the equation works the way it does.

Comment: In series, same AC current flows. The smaller capacitor has the bigger AC impedance. Thus, to make the same current flow, there should be bigger voltage on smaller capacitor.

Comment: It is like resistors in serial, big resistor has bigger voltage drop.

Comment: Ah, I think you phrased my question better or me. Why does smaller capacitance create larger impedance? This is like the opposite of resistors, where larger resistance means a larger voltage drop.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought the definition of capacitance was the ability to store charge

Capacitance isn't a measure of how much charge a capacitor can store. It's a measure of how much charge a capacitor can store **for a given voltage**. Just as the formula implies.

A 2nF capacitor charged to 1V will store twice the charge of a 1nF capacitor charged to 1V.